# Heroku with AWS RDS: Are details in database.yml needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-web-services

We're running a Rails app on Heroku and have it connected to a database on Amazon RDS. It works fine, the security zone is configured and the app is live.

Heroku requires you to provide a Database URL in the format of

```
mysql2://user:pass@rdsinstance.com/database
```

Since we're specifying the DB info in the add-on, what do we need to provide in the `database.yml` file, if anything?

Would the following suffice, or do we need even less than that? Maybe just the adapter name?

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku automatically replaces the content of any `database.yml` file on deploy with the value of the shared database, normally stored in the `SHARED_DATABASE_URL` config variable.

I don't know if it's save to override that value. If you do it, you should be able to connect to the database from Rails without any additional effort.
If your app is working fine and you are just wondering what you need to write inside the default `database.yml` file, then you can put in whatever you want, Heroku will replace it in any case on deploy.

Comment: Many thanks Simone, that makes sense. I'll omit the usual username/password details in the database.yml file in that case.

Comment: Here's a page that describes Heroku's treatment of `database.yml` and `DATABASE_URL`: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#build-behavior